# Snapshot'ing the event handler value as method argument in C#

Tags: c#, events, delegates

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023681/invoke-of-an-eventhandler) (and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282894/event-handler-raising-method-convention)) there's this example of snapshoting the event handler value before invoking:

```
var tmp = _myEventHandler;
if(tmp != null) {
    tmp(sender, args);
}
```

However, if I pass in the event handler and args into a function does this do the same thing?

```
protected void Invoke(MyEventHandler handler, MyEventArgs args)
{
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, args);
}
```

I would say yes, but after thinking about this I don't know if it is the same - like could an optimization process inline this function and remove the snapshot variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It indeed does the same thing.  The code is simply checking that the event handler is non-null and hence available for raising.  This code is no different for a field / parameter / local.  The C# compiler or JITer cannot inline this in such a way that the temporary is removed because it would change the semantics of the program.

Comment: This is a good explanation. A parameter is just like a local variable. It has the same semantics.

Answer (score 0):

The race condition is explained in your other links, such as [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7023719/161457).

As @JaredPar points out, your code effectively does the same thing. However, it violates the standard event conventions for .NET, which recommend the following:

```
protected virtual void OnAlarmRaised(AlarmRaisedEventArgs e)
```

You are free to violate the pattern, but doing so goes against the grain for minimal (if any) benefit.